# Using a Chart Web Part to show the number of items created per day

Tags: web-part, item, chart-web-part, chart

I'm trying to create a chart that shows dates along the x-axis and the number of items created in a certain list on each date along the y-axis. I've tried a number of things including sourcing from a view that groups by date and using another column with the date (not time) as plain text, but nothing seems to work. Advice?